# Run two docker containers from subdirectory does not find config file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to run two docker containers via docker-compose.

The following project structure is present:

```
|- service
   |- docker-compose
   |- DockerFile
   |- config.yaml

|- client
   |- docker-compose
   |- DockerFile
```

I try to run two containers via the following command:

```
$ docker-compose -f ./client/docker-compose.yml -f ./service/docker-compose.yml up
```

Everything seems to be working just fine, except for one error message:

```
{"action":"startup","error":"config file 'config.yaml' not found.","level":"error","msg":"could not load config","time":"2020-03-17T15:17:19Z"}
```

But when I navigate into each directory and run them separately everything works just fine. So it seems that the config file which is stated in the *volume* is somehow not found.

The docker-compose file is:

**./service/docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  thing:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    - --config-file
    - config.yaml
   ports:
    - 8080:8080
   volumes:
    - ./config.yaml:/config.yaml
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
    - web_host=http://my-site.com:8080
    depends_on:
    - anotherThing
    links: thing:thing.com
version: '3.4'
```

The configuration file itself has some arbitrary info:

```
---
authentication:
  my_arbitrary_key:
    enabled: true
```

Any idea how to make sure the config file is found when running docker-compose from a sub-directory? Or am I misusing the docker-compose command...

---

## Update

Interestingly enough if I swap the files in the docker-compose command I get it doesn't run.

So when I use:

```
$ docker-compose -f ./service/docker-compose.yml -f ./client/docker-compose.yml up
```

Docker doesn't run and the error is:

```
Cannot create container for service thing: invalid volume specification: '/Users/user/Site/service/config.yaml:config.yaml:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'config.yaml' mount path must be absolute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking for config file in outer directory, you could use absolute path or put it in some .env

Best practice would be to use single docker-compose file which could have relative path of other folder

Brief background : Docker-compose is utility to run multiple docker containers - called as services, - Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration. To learn more about all the features of Compose, see the list of features.

Hence it's not necessary to have two docker-compose files over here , we should have one which will start both services also you can user docker-compose to run one service if required

Find more details at - https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: A single docker-compose.yml Instead of two separate docker-compose.yml files you mean? Bare with me, I'm quite new to Docker. But isn't it nice that with the two docker-compose.yml files the services can also be built (and deployed) independant from one another?

Comment: But I also want to be able to run the two applicatino (client and server) separately and independant. If I have one docker-compose.yml file then that isn't the case.

Comment: Ah, but I can run those by adding them after `docker-compose up service1 service2 etc.`.  Perfect.